# Перенос Google Tag Manager из Jinja2 во Vue3

Tags: javascript, python, vue3, jinja2, google-tag-manager

Имею бэкенд на Django 3.2 + Jinja2. Имею шаблон, основанный на стандартном GTM-сниппете.

```html
{% if GTM_ID %}
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id={{ GTM_ID }}" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>    
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','{{ GTM_ID }}');</script>
{% endif %}
```

Он втыкается прямо после тега `<body>` и исправно работает.

Имею фронтенд Vue 3 (Vite), при этом корневой HTML рендерится именно бэком. Грубо говоря вот такой шаблон

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ ASSETS_URL }}css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
{{ render_gtm()|safe }}
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="module" src="{{ ASSETS_URL }}js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

где `render_gtm` это jinjaglobal, рендерящий шаблон из самого начала вопроса.

Общая задача - снизить зависимость от Jinja2 и утащить максимум кода во Vue 3.

Вопрос: **Как правильно утащить GTM из Jinja2 во Vue компонент, чтобы не сломать ему инициализацию?** Обязательно ли его втыкать в DOM или можно утащить в модуль? Поделитесь опытом.

Внутри GTM живут GA и ЯМ.

**UPD:** Вопрос о доставке `GTM_ID` на фронтенд не стоит. Имеется рабочий механизм. Представьте что это константа/литерал, известная на этапе синхронной загрузки страницы, скажем в скрипт внутри `<head>`. Вопрос только про практику интеграции самого GTM на фронте.

```js
const gtm = getConfig('GTM_ID'); // вернёт строку 'GTM-XXXXXX'
```

Comment: Возможно, не совсем правильно понимаю, в чём конкретно вопрос, но знаю, что всё зависит от того, насколько "сразу" вам необходимо отслеживать действия пользователей. Чем "скорее" скрипт GTM'а обработается, инициализируется, тем больше маркетологи в своих аналитических сервисах получат информации о взаимодействии с приложением/сайтом. Если до момента, когда Vue вывалит контент на сайт, пользователю ни с чем другим нечем взаимодействовать, то пусть GTM лежит в модуле (если правильно, понимаю, что такое модуль)

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st Спасибо. Модуль, грубо говоря это на фронтендерском означает отдельный js файл, который либо подключается через import из другого модуля, либо через тег script с указанием src. Я уже в процессе решения этой задачи, но пока приоритеты другие.

Comment: Ну, значит, верно понял. Думаю, если вы поделитесь своей окончательной реализацией (по возможности, конечно), то всем будет полезно. По крайней мере, мне самому бы хотелось узнать, как другие с помощью того же Vue или React внедряют GTM и внедряют ли вообще.